# Theme.spacing is not a function

Tags: jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

I have recently migrated my react app from material-ui v3 to v4 and replaced '@material-ui/core/styles' with '@material-ui/styles',for testing we have used jest and enzyme.Tests failed after migration.How can I resolve this issue? Errors are as follows:

Warning: Material-UI: the `styles` argument provided is invalid.
    You are providing a function without a theme in the context.
    One of the parent elements needs to use a ThemeProvider.
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: theme.spacing is not a function]
Full DOM rendering › encountered a declaration exception
TypeError: theme.spacing is not a function

```
  17 |   },
  18 |   selectEmpty: {
> 19 |     marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
     |                      ^
  20 |   },
```

Comment: There is an issue on the github repo regarding this exact question https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15976 might come handy for you :)

Comment: I have used createMuiTheme still tests are failing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to wrap every test with ThemeProvider. This resolves the issue.
Example:

```
    wrapper = mount(
      <ThemeProvider>
        <Dropdown handleSelect={handleSelectSpy} options={options} />
      </ThemeProvider>,
    );
```

Comment: You shouldn't _have_ to though. MUI always has a default theme, so unless you've added custom properties that don't exist on the default theme, it should be fine.

Answer (score 12):

Material UI old version is like import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';

but they have updated new version like that import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

Comment: But there is a 'hook' issue if you use '@material-ui/core/styles' instead of 'import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/styles'' under the react class context.

Comment: @JourneyWoo what's the issue?

Comment: This is the correct answer. I was just doing the wrong import and getting this error. Make sure to import from '@material-ui/core/styles'

Comment: it's not right, there is a case that you don't want to install the `@material-ui/core` and just install `@material-ui/styles`